Leaflet post popup properties to sidebar
I am building a game map for a friend and have run into an interesting way to do their popup content. Basically the popups are going to have history over each section so I decided that displaying it in a scrollable sidebar would be the better option. I installed the leaflet plugin Sidebar-V2 and have it running. I also am using a geoJSON variable to dynamically grab multiple parameters of the popup content. So far I'll have title, type, image and content.
Here is my javascript code:
//Add GeoJSON
var geojson = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "features": [
              {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                  "name": "Test",
                  "group": "majorcity",
                  "image": "test.png",
                  "popupcontent": "<p>Hello world!</p>"
                },
                "geometry": {
                  "coordinates": [
                    1741.5,
                    1000.5
                  ],
                  "type": "Point"
                },
                "id": 0
              },
              {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                  "name": "Test2",
                  "group": "village",
                  "image": "test.png",
                  "popupcontent": "<p>different popup!</p>"
                },
                "geometry": {
                  "coordinates": [
                    1800,
                    1200
                  ],
                  "type": "Point"
                },
                "id": 1
              }
            ]
          }
    ]
  };

  //Create dynamic popups from GeoJSON
 L.geoJSON(geojson).bindPopup(function(layer) {
    return '<h3>' + layer.feature.properties.name + '</h3>' 
    + '<p>' + layer.feature.properties.popupcontent + '</p>';
  }).addTo(map);

var image = L.imageOverlay('images/volucris_map_BASE.png', bounds).addTo(map);

//Trigger console on click
var marker = L.marker([1800, 1000],{title: "Title" }  ).addTo(map);
marker.bindPopup("This is popup content");
marker.on('click', onClick);

function onClick(e) {
   var popup = e.target.getPopup();
   var content = popup.getContent();

   console.log(content);
   postToSidebar(content);
}

function postToSidebar(content) {
    document.getElementById('sidebar-popup-content').innerHTML = content;
    sidebar.open('home');
}


So what I do have working is when I add a manual popup with the L.marker I successfully have posted the single property to the content box and opened the sidebar on click. This works great, however I need a way to get this to work with the dynamic geoJSON markers along with multiple parameters. What could I use to pass from the popup bind to the onClick/postToSidebar?
I also tried using a click event from leaflet documentation but they don't have a marker specific one from what I'm searching. I've searched over some of the similar stackoverflow topics as well for this same topic but nothing seems to use the stack I am using. Most are able to achieve this with React but I am limited to doing this in raw html/js due to where it will be placed in the future.
EDIT: I have somewhat gotten a bit further. I now am able to post the popup content to the sidebar using the geojson markers. However, I still can't find a way to do this on each click. I've tried openPopup already. I also tried taking my JSON variable and converting it to an array with only the coords without any luck. I just need some sort of way to grab the current clicked marker's JSON properties and I can connect the two functions.
Here is my current code:
//Add GeoJSON
const geojson = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "FeatureCollection",
            "features": [
              {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                  "name": "Test",
                  "group": "majorcity",
                  "image": "test.png",
                  "popupcontent": "<p>Hello world!</p>"
                },
                "geometry": {
                  "coordinates": [
                    1741.5,
                    1000.5
                  ],
                  "type": "Point"
                },
                "id": 0
              },
              {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                  "name": "Test2",
                  "group": "village",
                  "image": "images/volucris_map_BASE.png",
                  "popupcontent": "<p>different popup!</p>"
                },
                "geometry": {
                  "coordinates": [
                    1800,
                    1200
                  ],
                  "type": "Point"
                },
                "id": 1
              }
            ]
          }
    ]
  };

//Create dynamic popups from GeoJSON
var popup = L.popup();

var majorCity  = L.icon({
  iconUrl: 'images/markers/majorCity.svg',
  iconSize: [60,60],
  iconAnchor: [30,30]
});

var geojsonLayer = L.geoJSON(geojson, {
  // pointToLayer: function(geoJsonPoint, latlng) {
  //   return 
  //     L.marker(latlng, {
  //       icon: majorCity
  //     })
  // },
  onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
    if (feature.geometry.type === 'Point') {
      layer.bindPopup(layer.feature.properties.name);
      onClick(layer);
    }
  }
}).addTo(datamap);

var image = L.imageOverlay('images/volucris_map_BASE.png', bounds).addTo(datamap);

//Trigger console on click
function onClick(layer) {
   var title = layer.feature.properties.name;
   var content = layer.feature.properties.popupcontent;
   var image = layer.feature.properties.image;
   var group = layer.feature.properties.group;
   
   postToSidebar(title, content, image, group);
}

function postToSidebar(title, content, image, group) {
  var popupImage = document.getElementById('popup-img');
    document.getElementById('sidebar-pop-title').innerHTML = title;
    document.getElementById('popup-subheading').innerHTML = group;
    popupImage.src = image;
    document.getElementById('sidebar-popup-content').innerHTML = content;
    sidebar.open('home');
}


You can add a callback to popupopen event, and update its content (html). See this example.

I did try something very similar to this and it does not work if I am using the geoJSON and not a static placed marker. I won't be using static markers at all and am unsure how to get it to work with the JSON markers. Is there something else that would help with that?
